# Maximizing minimum distance of elements of array in S1

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces, circles

On the interval $I = [0,1)$ define the distance $d(a,b) = min(|a-b|, 1-|a-b|)$.
This metric is equivalent to the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ or $S^1$.

Given an array $A = [x_0,...,x_{n-1}]$ of elements of $I$, we define its **spacing** as
$$s(A) = n \cdot \min_{i \neq j} \left[d(x_i, x_j) \cdot d\left(\frac in, \frac jn\right)\right]$$

Note that $s([x_0,x_1]) = d(x_0,x_1)$

1. For a fixed $n$, how do we find array of length $n$ with maximum spacing ?
2. Denoting the above maximum spacing as $c_n$, how does the sequence $\{c_n\}$ behaves for large $n$ ?

Its easy to see that $c_n \geq {1 \over n}$ (from equally spaced grid), but this bound is not tight. Using empirical examples, it can be shown that $c_8 \geq {4 \over 15}$, $c_{10} \geq {1 \over 5}$.

Clearly $c_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by zero, so  $\lim_{n} c_n $ must exist. Is this limit zero ?

Comment: I don't see why $c_n$ is necessarily monotonically decreasing. Maybe I don't understand something? Is the spacing of [0, 3/10, 3/5, 1/10, 4/5, 1/2, 1/5, 9/10, 2/5, 7/10] equal to 3/10?

Comment: And also, I think you should explain what motivated this particular definition of "spacing".